# Try to have rounded corners on a table

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple table, and I'd like to have the rounded borders.

Here is the fiddle I'm working on :

http://jsfiddle.net/KZxgV/3/

The problem I have is that the cells are rounded, but not the borders around :-(

Comment: I don't know if it matters much, but your -moz-border-radius is not the same as your -webkit-border-radius everywhere!

Comment: It was a mistake, thx for your report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey i think you may one div define in your table as like this

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/KZxgV/14/